# How to obtain records with a higher amount only in cases where there is duplication in the code field?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT pagos.id, codigo_factura as code, pagos.importe as amount 
FROM pagos INNER JOIN m_labores p ON (pagos.id_producto = p.id)
    INNER JOIN maquinas m ON (pagos.id_maquina = m.id) 
WHERE m.id = 561 AND fecha_registro BETWEEN '2022-10-11 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-18 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY pagos.id DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

The query returns the following data:

[image: Datos obtenidos]

The result I want:

[image: Resultado deseado]

I would like that if there are 2 records with the same *code*, the query would return only the record whose *amount* is greater.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT pagos.id, codigo_factura as code, pagos.importe as amount 
FROM pagos INNER JOIN m_labores p ON (pagos.id_producto = p.id)
    INNER JOIN maquinas m ON (pagos.id_maquina = m.id) 
WHERE m.id = 561 AND fecha_registro BETWEEN '2022-10-11 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-18 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY codigo_factura
HAVING pagos.importe > 0
ORDER BY pagos.id DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

This does not work for me because I want the records with a null *amount* to continue to appear in cases where *code* is not duplicated.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: GROUP BY + MAX()

Comment: I have tried this. The amount value is correct but the id is not. For the id it is taking the value of the registry with null amount.
I would like to have in that row all the data of the duplicate record whose amount is higher

Comment: Incorrect query may return correct output only randomly.. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY then edit the query until its synthactical correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT codigo_factura as code, MAX(pagos.importe) as amount 
FROM pagos 
INNER JOIN m_labores p ON (pagos.id_producto = p.id)
INNER JOIN maquinas m ON (pagos.id_maquina = m.id) 
WHERE m.id = 561 AND fecha_registro BETWEEN '2022-10-11 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-18 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY code
```

will return maximal `amount` per `codigo_factura`. These data may be used for to select according `id` value from another copy of the tables pack:

```
SELECT MAX(pagos.id) id, codigo_factura as code, pagos.importe as amount 
FROM pagos 
INNER JOIN m_labores p ON (pagos.id_producto = p.id)
INNER JOIN maquinas m ON (pagos.id_maquina = m.id) 
WHERE m.id = 561 AND fecha_registro BETWEEN '2022-10-11 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-18 23:59:59'
AND (codigo_factura, pagos.importe) IN (
    SELECT codigo_factura as code, MAX(pagos.importe) as amount 
    FROM pagos 
    INNER JOIN m_labores p ON (pagos.id_producto = p.id)
    INNER JOIN maquinas m ON (pagos.id_maquina = m.id) 
    WHERE m.id = 561 AND fecha_registro BETWEEN '2022-10-11 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-18 23:59:59' 
    GROUP BY code
    )
GROUP BY code, amount;
```

MAX() and GROUP BY in outer query allows to fix the situation when the same and at the same time maximal `amount` value matches more than one `id` for the same `codigo_factura`. May be MIN() is more safe for you - edit in this case.

PS. A half of the columns in your code have not table alias, and you have no provided tables structures.. maybe some tables are excess, and the above query can be simplified.

Comment: If the inner query returns null in the amount field, the outer query fails to obtain it (Example: '24686038JQ22', null). Is there any way to correct this? For the rest of the cases the query works fine

Comment: @JorgePalaciosZaratiegui For example, ```.. AND (codigo_factura, COALESCE(pagos.importe, -1)) IN (SELECT codigo_factura as code, COALESCE(MAX(pagos.importe), -1) as amount ..```. I.e. we replace NULL with `-1` (which cannot be stored in `pagos.importe`, is it?) then compare.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0 you can use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) window function as follows:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT pagos.id, codigo_factura as code, pagos.importe as amount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY codigo_factura ORDER BY pagos.importe DESC) AS rn 
    FROM pagos INNER JOIN m_labores p ON (pagos.id_producto = p.id)
        INNER JOIN maquinas m ON (pagos.id_maquina = m.id) 
    WHERE m.id = 561 AND fecha_registro BETWEEN '2022-10-11 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-18 23:59:59' 
)
SELECT id, code, amount
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY pagos.id DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

It will assign a ranking value to each "*codigo_factura*" by ordering on "*pagos.importe*" descendently (NULL values come first). Then filtering out all rows whose ranking differs from 1 will remove smaller values for matching "*codigo_factura*".

Comment: I can't use this query. It gives me an error: "WITH" is not valid at this position for this server version"

Comment: In this example it coincides that the correct id is the greater in both cases (3829 and 3826). However, it may not always be so.
I would like to have in that row all the data of the duplicate record whose amount is higher

Comment: Then input tables may be required for an efficient solution.

Comment: The `id` value needed may be not greatest one, so `MAX(id)` is not correct.

Comment: That's it. The same would happen if the query returned more values (like strings...).
These should always be the ones from the duplicate record that has the highest amount

Comment: One option to avoid further joins is building the ranking index using variables, but nothing can be attempted here without input tables declaration. In the best case scenario, you could also move the aggregation inside your subqueries.